# How to return rows based on a value

Tags: matlab

I am using MATLAB R2011b and I am having problems returning rows based on a value.
I have two .txt files with data in the format:

A:

```
1901    1.0     0.9    1.4   3.0    3.9   8.3    9.5     9.4    8.8     6.6   4.1   1.7
1902    0.3     2.4    1.5   3.7    5.1   8.3    10.4    10.3   7.6     5.9   2.7   0.7
1903    0.6     0.1    0.7   2.6    4.4   7.6    9.3    10.1    7.9     4.7  -0.7   1.2
```

B:

```
1901    5.9  7.0   8.2   10.5   14.3    17.1    17.6    18.6    16.5    13.2    10.2  6.6
1902    5.4  8.6   8.2   13.5   13.8    17.9    18.8    19.3    16.8    12.9    8.9   6.1
1903    5.3  6.1   7.7   11.0   14.3    18.0    17.5    18.1    16.6    11.9    5.8   6.5
```

If I use:

`D = [A(:,1), (B(:,2:13)-A(:,2:13))]`
and get:

```
1.901   0.0049  0.0061  0.0068  0.0075  0.0104  0.0088  0.0081  0.0092  0.0077  0.0066  0.0061  0.0049
1.902   0.0051  0.0062  0.0067  0.0098  0.0087  0.0096  0.0084  0.009   0.0092  0.007   0.0062  0.0054
1.903   0.0047  0.006   0.007   0.0084  0.0099  0.0104  0.0082  0.008   0.0087  0.0072  0.0065  0.0053
```

I expect D to be:

```
1901    4.9     6.1  6.8    7.5   10.4   8.8     8.1    9.2  7.7    6.6  6.1    4.9
1902    5.1     6.2  6.7    9.8   8.7    9.6     8.4    9.0  9.2    7.0  6.2    5.4
1903    4.7     6.0  7.0    8.4   9.9    10.4    8.2    8.0  8.7    7.2  6.5    5.3
```

Then I want to return the rows with maximum values in cloumns `D(:,2:end)`. In this case because 10.4 appears in twice:

```
1903    4.9  6.1    6.8  7.5    10.4    8.8     8.1     9.2   7.7    6.6    6.1  4.9
1905    4.7  6.0    7.0  8.4    9.9     10.4    8.2     8.0   8.7    7.2    6.5  5.3
```

I have tried:
`[Values, Rows] = max(max(max(D(:, 2:end), [], 13)))`
But I only get the maximum value i.e `10.4`.

Can someone please help?

Comment: The output is correct to a multiplier of `1E3`. In the Matlab display of `D`, is there any indication that this scaling is being done (usually to the top left of the printed matrix)?

Comment: @TroyHaskin its `1.0e+003 *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling 'max' wrong.
What you could do is:

```
[maxVal, idx] = max(D(:, 2:end), [], 'all', 'linear'); % returns the linear index of the max value
[rows, cols] = ind2sub(size(D(:, 2:end)), idx); % returns the row index and column index of the max value

D(rows, :) % show the row(s) with the max value
```

Note the column index refers to the matrix `D(:, 2:end)`, not the original matrix. So in this case the real column index would be `cols + 1`.

As to why your matrix `D` is seemingly shown wrong, it's because I'm assuming there is a `1.0e+03 *` in front of it. You can surely modify this behaviour with `format short` or something.

EDIT FOR PREVIOUS VERSIONS OF MATLAB:

For previous versions of Matlab where the 'linear' flag did not exist, you can do something like this:

```
maxVal = max(D(:, 2:end), [], 2); % get the max value in each row
rows = find(maxVal == max(maxVal)); % find ALL rows that have the same maximum value

D(rows, :)
```

NEW EDIT:

```
maxVal = max(D(:, 2:end), [], 2);
rows = [];
for i = 1:size(D, 1)
    if (any(D(i, 2:end) == maxVal))
        rows = [rows, i];
    end
end
D(rows, :)
```

or, in case `any()` did not exist yet either, substitute the for loop with this one

```
for i = 1:size(D, 1)
    for j = 2:size(D, 2)
        if (D(i, j) == maxVal)
            rows = [rows, i];
            break
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have used `[maxVal, idx] = max(D(:, 2:end), [], 'all', 'linear')
[rows, cols+1] = ind2sub(size(D(:, 2:end)), idx);
D(rows, :) `
And I get: `Error using max Too many input arguments.`

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: i am using R2011b

Comment: I'm assuming that the 'linear' flag (and possibly even the 'all' flag?) did not exist back then. I've edited the answer in a way that should work for you.

Comment: your edit works but it only returns the first row, i expect two rows, is there a way around it?

Comment: You're right, I've edited the answer (hoping that find existed in R2011b!)

Comment: Thanks for your help but your edit still returns one row.

Comment: Ok then, time for brute force: new edit added.

Comment: is there a reason why the second loop is not displaying displaying?

Comment: Like in all previous cases, just add the same displaying instruction.